# firebase subdomain is empty

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to Firebase invites and I have followed the documentation to implement a simple SMS and email invite. Everything works fine except for the generated URL in both the SMS and email. It is missing the app_code. This is the final URL

https://.app.goo.gl/i/remaining-part-of-the-url

There is no way to set dynamic link domain on the app invite intent and i don't know where to set/get the app code.

This is what i basically have:

```
Intent intent = new 
AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.firebase_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.firebase_message))
.setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.firebase_img)))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.firebase_cta))
                .setDeepLink(dynamicLinkUri)
               .build();
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
```